# Incorrect grouping SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case, grouping

I need to create an SQL Query that will use the following data:

```
shift_id, emp_id,   date,    starttime, endtime
   1    ,  55   , 2015-10-14, 06:00:00, 10:00:00
   2    ,  55   , 2015-10-15, 03:00:00, 13:00:00
   3    ,  52   , 2015-10-15, 07:00:00, 14:00:00
```

Then re-arrange it so that it shows the 'date' on top as a column with the starting day being the NEXT Sunday. I have begun an attempt below but if there are 2 employees (emp_id) working on the same day, it does not display grouped:

```
SELECT concat(firstname,' ', surname) AS 'Fname', 
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Sunday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Monday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 3 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Tuesday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 4 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Wednesday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 5 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Thursday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 6 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Friday`,
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Saturday`
FROM shifts NATURAL JOIN employees
GROUP BY Fname, date
```

Here is the result with showing the employee name twice instead of grouping? Where have I gone wrong?:

[image: Result]

Using GROUP_CONCAT, the incorrect result shows as below:

[image: Result2]

Comment: Hey jarlh, then it only shows the first result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are selecting more columns than you've specified in your GROUP BY.  As a result, MySQL will simply pick the data from one record in that group to represent it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**

Try something like this:

```
SELECT concat(firstname,' ', surname) AS 'Fname', 
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Sunday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 2 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime) END) `Monday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 3 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Tuesday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 4 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Wednesday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 5 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Thursday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 6 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Friday`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7 THEN concat(starttime,'-', endtime)  END) `Saturday`
FROM shifts NATURAL JOIN employees
GROUP BY Fname, date
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Llama, you have hit the hammer on the nail... Also removed  Group by 'date'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for ?
if not, please make a sample result.
The first **SELECT** is only to hide some tmp fields. If you get the result with a program you can remove it

```
SELECT Fname, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday
FROM (
  SELECT 
      @timestr:=  concat(starttime,'-', endtime) AS a,
      @datenr:= DAYOFWEEK(DATE) AS b,
      concat(firstname,' ', surname) AS 'Fname',
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 1, @timestr,''))  AS `Sunday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 2, @timestr,''))  AS `Monday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 3, @timestr,''))  AS `Tuesday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 4, @timestr,''))  AS `Wednesday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 5, @timestr,''))  AS `Thursday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 6, @timestr,''))  AS `Friday`,
      COALESCE( IF(@datenr  = 7, @timestr,''))  AS `Saturday`
  FROM shifts s
  LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.emp_id = s.emp_id
  GROUP BY s.date, s.emp_id
) AS result;
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, this is grouping the dates in the same day: http://imgur.com/SlIUK7b.jpg

Comment: If have change my Answer. please let me now if it OK